# Создание веб приложения на Intellij Idea community edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsf, primefaces

Кто нибудь пробовал создавать веб приложение(maven) на Intellij Idea Community edition, знаю что не поддерживает веб и java 2ee, но очень надо. Я попробовала подключить tomcat7, но когда обращаюсь к нему говорит что нет такого репозитория. jsf, и primefaces тоже не работают. Собираюсь делать большой веб проект, на Ultimate нету денег(((.

Comment: У Ultimate есть триал 30 дней. Юзайте Eclipse, он поддерживает веб разработку.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Все зависимости прописываете в maven, сервер поднимается отдельно, спокойно можете использовать его в качестве редактора кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У JetBrains есть 30 дневный trial для Ultimate, так же есть версия [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate EAP(Early Access Preview)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/EAP). Думаю этого вам будет, вполне достаточно для начала.

Comment: @InFloat, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не принципиально какой сервер использовать, то создайте maven или gradle проект с помощью http://start.spring.io/

Импортируйте проект в Idea и работайте с ним. Запускается и отлаживается.

Answer (score 1):

Где нибудь скачайте(github.com) и импортируйте этого проекта через пом.хмл а потом пожелании настройте драйвера, или пустой проект откройте, а затем запустит установку mavenа и он сам загружает автоматически из интернета, ну смотрите еще инструкции в интернете

Answer (score 1):

На [официальном сайте](//www.jetbrains.com/idea/) говорится, что maven поддерживается в community-версии:

[image: Скриншот сайта]